# Add Reference VS 2008 strange issue with paths

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, path, reference, version

I have VS 2008 Team Suite, and use TFS.

I have references in 2 folders in TFS:

path in TFS: $Arquitectura\Main\ReferenciasFrk\Release\
mapped to: C:\Trabajo\Arquitectura\Main\ReferenciasFrk\Release\

path in TFS: $Arquitectura\Main\Referencias Externas\
mapped to: C:\Trabajo\Arquitectura\Main\Referencias Externas\

I have project csproj, and I try Add Reference in project, and use Browse Tab for select the file dll. (right click on References and click Add Reference, go to the Browse tab )

The file dll that I want use is:

....\ReferenciasFrk\Release\Frk.Nsi.OracleDto.dll

Reale.Frk.Nsi.OracleDto, Version=**2.0.0.1**

When I have added the reference, in VS, window Properties, Reference Properties , the value of Path is:

C:\Trabajo\Arquitectura\Main\Referencias Externas\Frk.Nsi.OracleDto.dll
Version: **2.0.0.0**

the reference has other path and version !!!

I edit csproj file using notepad, and has this lines:

```
<Reference Include="Frk.Nsi.OracleDto, Version=2.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7090723f76dac05b, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\ReferenciasFrk\Release\Frk.Nsi.OracleDto.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The path is right, but VS shows in Reference Properties  another path.

Now, I clean, build (rebuild) Project, it generate Frk.Nsi.OracleDto.dll in bin\Release but the version is 2.0.0.0.

There aren't any version of Frk.Nsi.OracleDto.dll in GAC - no versions in GAC-

i don't understand anything; Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the *SpecificVersion* element to True.

Comment: it's works now, Iwould like know why if set SpecificVersion=true?

Comment: Setting the SpecificVersion element provides additional context to the reference resolver. In this case, you're telling it not to settle for an instance of the assembly with a different version, but to require an instance with the same version you specified.